# Using Java Class as a Mapper and Python Script as Reducer

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I am trying to run hadoop with streaming. I have two files . One is the java file for mapper and other is the python script for the reducer.

MerkleMapper.java

`Class MerkleMapper extends MapREduceBase` and defines `map()` function. For each record of the input split it reads the incoming `key(byte_offset)` , `value(line)` pair and outputs the `byte_offset` and hash of the line.

The Reducer is a python script which combines all the hashes and produces a top hash.

Is it possible to combine the two (java and python). How can i specify my java file as mapper using Streaming.

Answer (score 0):

You could split it into 2 jobs.

First job has only a mapper (your Java mapper) and you take the output of that and pass it into a python streaming job, where your Mapper is the identity mapper and your reducer is the python Reducer. Currently, you cannot combine streaming and java from what i know.